# Can one BT device control the display of another

Tags: bluetooth

If I pair devices can I have one instruct the other what it ought to display on its LCD?

Both devices are under my control, will be paired, etc, I just want to know if the protocol allows it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ‘protocol’ allows you to develop any protocol you like (as long as it doesn't take too much bandwidth, of course). So, the answer is yes.

If you're looking for some ‘ready’ solution, you should be more specific in what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Most BT devices have a serial HW port and all BT devices support RFCOMM protocol over the air. So if your LCD display can be controlled by simple RS232 type connection (and most can) then job done.